# What's the best solution for organizing a lot of images in Drupal8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have roughly 100 images to upload for a site that is being converted to drupal8. I was wondering what was the best way to organize them both in the actual project directory and if there was any way to organize them in the media tab.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve by using 
`https://www.drupal.org/project/imce` module

After installing this module you will be able to upload 100 images at once with categorization and use in the entire website where you want.